# How to know ODBC driver to which RDBMS connect?

Tags: odbc

I need away to Know the ODBC driver to which RDBMS (SQL or ORACLE) connect through c# code ?
I used odbcObjectname.driver property this property get the name of the ODBC driver specified for the current connection. If the odbcObjectname.driver = "sqlncli11.dll" I know that the driver connect to SQL database, but if dbcObjectname.driver = "SQORA32.DLL"  I know that the driver connect to ORACLE database. 
This way work correct if the user use the same driver I used but if the user want to use another driver my code will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make configurable list of known drivers (in central database, in configuration file, registry etc.). Then check if driver is on the list. If not the report it somehow to make check by yourself and modify list.